# Combining multiple IF AND statements

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on [a finance document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VDwTAKSqzKKf3gfSEol-AdzSrZgNrcEdJbREMO4e1zI/edit?usp=sharing) and trying to figure out the best way to create results based upon multiple outcomes from two drop downs. Effectively, what I'm trying to do is create different outcomes based upon the combination of the two dropdown, i.e.

if(H2=burn) and (I2=yes) do this (xyz)
if(H2=burn) and (I2=no) do this (xyz)
if(H2=fixed) and (I2=yes) do this (xyz)
if(H2=fixed) and (I2=no) do this (xyz)

I can use AND to create:

```
IF(AND(H2="Burn",I2="Yes"),(E2+C2-sum(K2:M2)),"No")
```

which gives me an outcome for the first line being true and if it's false, but not for the other combinations. Have been looking at nested IF statements, but I can't get that to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I also only want one result for any combination. So only four possible outcomes, rather than a "True" and "False" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was what I was looking for:

```
=IF(AND(H2="Burn",I2="Yes"),"Outcome 1",IF(AND(H2="Burn",I2="No"),"Outcome 2",IF(AND(H2="Fixed",I2="Yes"),"Outcome 3",IF(AND(H2="Fixed",I2="No"),"Outcome 4"))))
```

Comment: Did it work? You can use nested IFs to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Put your other IFs in place of NO with proper braces.  `IF(X=Y, do this, (IF(X=Z), do this, (IF(X=A), do this, "NO")))`

https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/support-tip-build-nested-IF

Comment: But that doesn’t account for two elements being true. If x=a and y=b do a etc. All that seems to achieve is multiple nested IFs